# Sum elements from substring after picewise rising them to power of two

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, increment, dna-sequence

Let's say a have a function. The function recives a string as parameter.
The function is one of a class functions. After reciving a string, it calculates some variables based on substrings.
In one part of the process, i need to append key:value pairs to a dictionary.
Those values should be calculated from several parts of the mentioned string, but each following char need (after conversion to int) to be raised to a specific power of two. The powers are raised by 1 from 0 to end of substring.
I'm afraid i do not know how to solve the incementation-part of raising to power of two:

```
    self.topologia = {}
    for i in range(0, 6):
        if int(dna[17 + i * 8]) == 1:
            self.topologia[self.ile_warstw] = sum(list(map(lambda: x * Math.Pow(2, ?), int(dna[17 + i * 8:17 + i * 8 + 7]))))
            self.ile_warstw += 1
```

The question mark indicates the part i'm unable to solve.
The string is made of 0s and 1s only.

Edit - clarification purpose:

what i wish to do is: 
E = x1*2^0 + x2*2^1 + x3*2^2 + x4*2^3 + ... + xn*2^(n-1)

Comment: you could just do, `x**2`, !!

Comment: @FazilZaid 
correct me if i'm wrong, but x ** 2 will rise every element to the power of two once: x1^2, x2^2, x3^2,
what i wish to do is this:
x1*2^0, x2*2^1, x3*2^2, x4*2^3, ..., xn*2^(n-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can `enumerate` your data and then feed both the value and the enumeration to your lambda function:

```
    self.topologia = {}
    for i in range(0, 6):
        if int(dna[17 + i * 8]) == 1:
            self.topologia[self.ile_warstw] = sum(list(map(lambda x: x[1] * math.pow(2, x[0]), enumerate(int(dna[17 + i * 8:17 + i * 8 + 7])))))        
            self.ile_warstw += 1
```

And then an alternative to `math.pow(2, n)` is `1 << n` giving the following code:

```
            self.topologia[self.ile_warstw] = sum(list(map(lambda x: x[1] * (1 << x[0]), enumerate(int(dna[17 + i * 8:17 + i * 8 + 7])))))
```